# Sharepoint 2007: breaking role inheritence in item checked in "disappears" the item

Tags: c#, sharepoint

We have a bug in our sharepoint 2007 site.
We have an event receiver of ItemCheckedIn for document library. Here is the code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(itemUrl))
    {
         using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()
         {
             SPListItem item = web.GetListItem(itemUrl);
             item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
         }
    }
});
```

This code in the event causes that when a user check in an item, it "disappears" the item from the AllItems.aspx page, but when the user refreshes the pages the file is there again with the copied permissions from the library.

Any ideas why would it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but..

Maybe you need an `item.Update()` after de BreakRoleInheritance syntax?

```
{
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPListItem item = web.GetListItem(itemUrl);
item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
item.Update();
}
```

Comment: try set AllowUnsafeUpdates for web..
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true; (added in the code above)